# how can i get back to normal mode from insert mode on google colab

Tags: vim, google-colaboratory

Recently I started using Vim key-bindings on Google Colab.

After entering insert mode in a coding cell, it's impossible to go back normal mode by pressing `<ESC>` or `<Ctrl + ]>`. Doing so takes me to a command mode of Google Colab instead, and I will never be able to enter normal mode of the coding cell.

Is there any good way to return normal mode?

Answer (score 3):

I met the similar issue. I think this might be caused by the chrome vimium plugin, you can disable it or add exclusion rules for the coloab website in the vimium plugin.

ref:

- [When using the Vim editor, I cannot switch back to normal mode from insert mode - Overleaf](https://ru.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/When_using_the_Vim_editor,_I_cannot_switch_back_to_normal_mode_from_insert_mode)